# On Roblox I'm trying to make it so that when you use a proximity prompt a image label becomes visible and stays visible even when you rejoin

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local proximity = workspace.Cardpack.ProximityPrompt --GUI.Enabled = true
local proximityPromptService = game.GetService("ProximityPromptService")

proximity.Triggered:Connect(function()
    game.Workspace.Inventory.Frame.X1.Visble = true
end)
```

Comment: You've asked how to make it start visible even after you leave and rejoin, this gets into persistent data and requires the use of  [DataStores](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Data-store). You should get that set up first.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple just creat datastore with your script and when click set datastore value and when player join getasync and if value true show else wait the proximity prompt